# Why is phase difference measured using quadrature readout?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

Sometimes when measuring the phase difference $\phi$ between two beams (such as when measuring the refractive index of gas in a gas cell), the intensity is measured both when they are added directly and when they are added with an additional $\pi/2$ phase shift; from these two intensity measurements $\phi$ can be found, known as 'quadrature readout'.

What is the advantage of this compared to simply using the single intensity measurement from adding them directly (assuming the point of zero phase difference is known)?

Surely any fluctuation to $\phi$ will affect both intensity measurements equally. The only thing I can think of is if the source has fluctuating intensity which can be corrected for by subtracting the two measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re basically right: By measuring in quadrature, the amplitude and phase components can be disentangled. That way, amplitude fluctuations don’t affect your phase difference measurement.